# Why are sudoers not defined by UID?

Tags: linux, user-accounts, sudoers

Login information is tied to UIDs in Linux. However, when I open the sudoers file the sudoers are defined by username instead of UID.

Why are used usernames instead of UID?
Does the sudoers file automatically change when `usermod -l` is run?

Snippet:

```
    # User privilege specification
    root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Comment: _You can insert comments by prefixing them with a # but this is also used to specify a uid in certain parts of the file when it is followed by a number_ [see here for example](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers)

Comment: @Hastur Okay so it's possible to refer to uid's by prefixing them with a #. Why isn't this done by default? i.e.:  
  
`#0    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`  
  
instead of  
  
`root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`  
  
It's kinda strange to tie these security rules to a specific username or groupname since they can be changed. User ID's and Group ID's cannot be changed.

Comment: You can change UID and GUID,  starting from the `etc/passwd` (_etc etc_) and doing `chown -R newUID:newGUID` with some additional care... BTW The idea is to create alias for sudo groups, for group of group, and so on ... so the UID should became quickly a mess to administrate... but the definitive answer I suppose you can have only from the one who did it and __still__ is improving it and working on... (Todd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following some manuals [[1](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers),[2](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/8/usermod)] I can give you these answers:

1. **It's possible to indicate the users with the UID**.

   From the [sudoers wiki of ubuntu](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers) we can read:

   > You can insert comments by prefixing them with a # but this is also used to specify a uid in certain parts of the file when it is followed by a number.

   Later in the [Runas aliases section](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers#Runas_Aliases) is reported an example:

   > ```
   > # UID 0 is normally used for root  
   > # Note the hash (#) on the following line indicates a uid, not a comment.  
   > Runas_Alias ROOT = #0
   > ```
2. **When you do simply `usermod -l` you should not propagate the change in the sudoers.**
   Indeed from the [man page for usermod](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/8/usermod), more informative than the [BSD one](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/usermod.8?query=usermod&sec=8), we can read

   > **-l, --login NEW_LOGIN**
   >   The name of the user will be changed from LOGIN to NEW_LOGIN. **Nothing else is changed.**
   >   In particular, the user's home directory name should probably be changed manually to  reflect the new login name.

   It seems still to imply a manual care of the modification in the sudoers if you specify only `-l` parameter. Probably you have to erase the old username and [add the user to the sudo group](https://askubuntu.com/a/168289/196535) with

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G sudo hduser
   ```

   Indeed so it happened at [this user](http://narkive.com/17hpw4SY:1.769.190) in the 2008 with a Debian Sid system:

   > I used to use XXX as username to login to my sid laptop and
   >   XXX is in sudoers file. today I changed it to YYY using
   >
   > `sudo usermod -l YYY XXX`
   >
   > I did nothing else.
   >
   > Now I can login using YYY but I was not able to su to root using
   >   the root password. **Also 'YYY' is not in sudoers file so now I
   >   can not edit /etc/sudoers to include YYY**.

Finally **why**, probably you should obtain a definitive answer only from [Todd Miller](http://www.sudo.ws/todd/) who did the last (winning) fork of sudo in 1991, or maybe from Bob Coggeshall or Cliff Spencer if it comes from 1980 [[7](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/306766:linux-101-introduction-to-sudo)].

**References**

- The [wiki of Ubuntu](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers) about sudoers.
- The [Runas aliases section](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers#Runas_Aliases).
- The man page for [usermod](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/8/usermod).
- The man page for usermod, [BSD one](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/usermod.8?query=usermod&sec=8).
- Ask Ubuntu [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/168289/196535) about how to add a user to sudo group.
- [The guy who did `usermod -l`](http://narkive.com/17hpw4SY:1.769.190).
- Some [historical notes](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/306766:linux-101-introduction-to-sudo) about sudo.
- The Todd Miller's [homepage](http://www.sudo.ws/todd/).

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. So for example, if I create a user A and give him full privileges then delete user A after a while and forget to remove his specific username from the sudoers file, then after another while I create an account for user B which happens to have the same username as A had then B will happen to have full privileges on the system as well? Along with the story from 'The guy who did `usermod -l`' you referenced I am wondering why this design is still being used nowadays, doesn't really make sense... Thanks for your time and effort though.